# jQuery: scrollTop is not working if element is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

scrollTop function is working fine but only if element is WITHOUT setting ***display: none***;

I have one main element eWindow, inside this element there are many others elements with some JavaScript code, Ajax calls and so on. After everything is finished I just want to show this main element eWindow. So I will set display: block;

But this solution is not working for me. If I just remove from my stylesheet display: none, the scrollTop will start working correctly.

Comment: Why would one want to control scrollTop while the element is not visible in any case?!

Comment: *`"But this solution is not working for me"`* what solution?

Comment: add your code to give us the possibility to mean where is the problem

Comment: Why? Because I need to scroll page inside element to specific possition and after it show page to user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that ***visibility: hidden*** hides the element, taking up space in the layout. While ***display: none*** removes the element from the document, even though the HTML is in the source code.

I've created an example for you, to understand what's going on. Obviously that I don't know much about your project, so have that in mind ( http://jsbin.com/jociy/1 ).

The reason why you can not scrollTo the display:none element, is that the element does not take any space between rendered elements - there's no X or Y position on the window that this element actually exist, so there's no value to scroll to!

Let's see the following code, that exemplifies this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#scrollTo').on('click', function(){

    // get the element position
    var toPosition = $(".scrollTo").offset().top;

    // scroll to the element position
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: toPosition
    }, 'slow', function(){

      $(".scrollTo")
        .css("background-color", "")
        .css("background-color", "black");

      // let's remove the element after awhile
      setTimeout(function(){

        $(".scrollTo")
          .fadeOut(function(){

            $(this).css("display", "none");

            alert("If you click on 'Click to ScrollTo this time, it wont work as expected, because the element does not take any position between the rendered elements.'");

          });

      }, 3000);

    });

 });

});
```

Some HTML elements to help you with this:

```
  <button id="scrollTo">Click to ScrollTo!</button>

  <div class="foo red">I'm red!</div>
  <div class="foo green">I'm green!</div>
  <div class="foo blue">I'm blue!</div>
  <div class="foo yellow">I'm yellow!</div>
  <div class="foo red">I'm red!</div>
  <div class="foo green">I'm green!</div>
  <div class="foo blue">I'm blue!</div>
  <div class="foo yellow">I'm yellow!</div>
  <div class="foo red">I'm red!</div>
  <div class="foo green">I'm green!</div>
  <div class="foo blue scrollTo">I'm blue!</div>
  <div class="foo yellow">I'm yellow!</div>
  <div class="foo red">I'm red!</div>
  <div class="foo green">I'm green!</div>
  <div class="foo blue">I'm blue!</div>
  <div class="foo yellow">I'm yellow!</div>
  <div class="foo red">I'm red!</div>
  <div class="foo green">I'm green!</div>
  <div class="foo blue">I'm blue!</div>
  <div class="foo yellow">I'm yellow!</div>
  <div class="foo green">I'm green!</div>
  <div class="foo blue scrollTo">I'm blue!</div>
  <div class="foo yellow">I'm yellow!</div>
  <div class="foo red">I'm red!</div>
  <div class="foo green">I'm green!</div>
  <div class="foo blue">I'm blue!</div>
  <div class="foo yellow">I'm yellow!</div>
  <div class="foo red">I'm red!</div>
  <div class="foo green">I'm green!</div>
  <div class="foo blue">I'm blue!</div>
  <div class="foo yellow">I'm yellow!</div>
```

The example CSS style:

```
.foo {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 25px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #000;
}
```

A possible solution, could be for example, set opacity to 0, height to 0px! Or keep the visibility:hidden! Or, in case the display:none happens client side, you can before modifying the element, get all eWindow element position and save it on a collection, for future reference!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about the details of your project but there are two things that come to my mind.

First, perhaps you can execute the **scrollTop()** just before you change the display to none, so if the element will be shown the next time it will already be scrolled to top.

Then you could try to hide the element without changing display to none but instead channging its **opacity**, things like fadeOut() or hide() / show()

perhaps that helps..